# R parallel computing inconsistent results

Tags: r, foreach, parallel-processing

I am trying to speed up my R script by using parallel processing since it is computationally demanding.

After much research and testing, I have finally (I think !) got it working. However, my output is different every time I run the foreach loop on the exact same data. What could I be doing wrong ?

cl <- makeCluster(detectCores()-2)

registerDoSNOW(cl)

x <- foreach(i = 1:35, .combine = "c") %dopar% {

my code ...

return(percentageerror)}

Inside the code body I am  doing some machine learning on a data set, and returning my percentage error.

My returned percentageerror  result is slightly different every time I run the code.

What I would ideally like is the result of each loop iteration to be stored, and then once the loop has finished, calculate the mean of the stored results.

Comment: please, provide reproducible example

Comment: Are you doing anything that involves random sampling?  Cross-validation?

Comment: I would define the function outside the `foreach` and call it after `%dopar%{` instead of defining it inside the `foreach`

Comment: Replace the **dopar** with **do** and see if you are still getting different results. With this approach you can figure out if the issue is indeed due to parallel processing. Ideally if you write the code within foreach as a function and then put *.export="function_name"*  while calling foreach , you can safeguard variable overwrites and other basic issues due to poor coding.

Comment: The issue is still there when changing dopar to do, so you are correct, it has nothing to do with the parrelisation.  How can the function be defined outside the foreachloop  if it depends on the iterator i ?

Comment: Update - solved.  The issue was not doing set.seed(1)  before my code. My neural network needs that for consistency.